# Angular function like selectize.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I would like to know if there's something similar to selectize.js 'Single Item Select' with 'Create: True'?

I want to have a dropdown searchable list. If the item is not in the searched list, the user can Add it.

**Searchable list:**
[image]

**Adding item to that lis:**
[image]

Comment: And whats wrong with _selectize.js_?

Comment: I need something without jQuery.